# Invalid data when reading hash table

Tags: hashtable

The following code should go through a hash table and use keys / values to filter one big log file into separate files for each key, using values for regex matching:

```
# get today's date, or override with user-entered date
param($workingdate=(get-date).ToString("yyMMdd"))

# set hash table for each profile
$filters = @{
"desa" = "filtering string for desa";
"unpd" = "filtering string for unpd";
"dpad" = "filtering string for dpad";
"dsd" = "filtering string for dsd"
}
Foreach ($profilename in ("desa", "unpd", "dpad", "dsd")
)
{
#filter the main log and copy the filtered sub-set into individual profile logs
Write-Host "Matching regex for $profilename is $filters[profilelname]"
Get-Content "access-$workingdate.log" | Select-string -pattern $filters[$profilename] | Set-Content "$profilefilename-$workingdate.log"
}
```

The result gives me the screen output

```
Matching regex for desa is System.Collections.Hashtable[desa]
Matching regex for unpd is System.Collections.Hashtable[unpd]
Matching regex for dpad is System.Collections.Hashtable[dpad]
Matching regex for dsd is System.Collections.Hashtable[dsd]
```

and no filtered target files.

What am I doing wrong...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I have found out why I wasn't able to output the content of that hash table. The problem was in way I called objects from that hash table. The following fails:

```
Write-Host "Matching regex for $profilename is $filters[profilelname]"
```

When I changed it to:

```
Write-Host "Matching regex for $profilename is" $filters.profilelname
```

It worked. Because it was in quotes, it didn't actually resolve the hash table properly.